# How to shrink the headers / chapters in dissertation?

Tags: header-footer, fontsize

I want to reduce the font size for headers (chapters). As you can see in the picture, the header is too big. Is there any command that will do the job?

My dissertation TeX file contains 1-chapters, 2-Main  and 3-ref. All commands have been written in the Main file.

Following are the all packages which I use.

```
\usepackage[T1,T5]{fontenc}

\usepackage{colordvi,cite,comment,color}
\usepackage{subfigure}

%\usepackage{amsbsy,amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amsxtra}

\usepackage{epsfig,fancyhdr,latexsym}

\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}

\usepackage{amscd}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{showlabels}

\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{cancel}

\usepackage{todonotes}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=black}

\hypersetup{citecolor=black}

\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}

\usepackage{sectsty}

\allsectionsfont{\normalsize\raggedright}
```

[image]

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ. Is it a template that you must use in order for your thesis to satisfy the school's formatting requirements?

Comment: You mention that, in your opinion, the font size used in chapter-level headers is "too big" and that you want to reduce the font size. How much smaller? 5% smaller? 10% smaller? 40% smaller? Please be specific.

Comment: Its " \documentclass[12pt]{article} "  Yes they asked me to reduce size make same as body text.  @Mico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you employ the `article` document class, you could issue the following instructions in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\normalsize\raggedright}
```

If this doesn't work, it may be because you're also loading packages, such as `titlesec`, which affect the appearance of sectioning headers. If that's the case, do please provide more information about the contents of the preamble of your document.

Comment: Thank You , it got smaller but it's not enough. How can I make it smaller that it?

Comment: @Redshoes - Do please state whether you use any packages that influence fonts and font sizes.

Comment: I just updated my post

Comment: @Redshoes - If I use the preamble code you provided, employ `\documentclass[12pt]{article}` per an earlier comment of yours, and hand-type the `\section` directive contained in the screenshot you posted, I do *not* get the output you show: The font size is smaller, there is no "CHAPTER" prefix, and the material is typeset ragged-right rather than fully justified. In short, there *must* be additional code in your document that affects the appearance of section-level headers. Unless you provide the missing pieces of information, there's not much more I can provide advice on.

Comment: Thanks, I got it done.